# Dynamic watermark on Moodle videos

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, moodle, video.js

I am a novice moodle administrator and, in addition, they ask me for things that I think are out of the ordinary. My users need their videos to have a dynamic watermark to prevent piracy.

I have evaluated some options, such as VDO Cipher, but they seem too expensive for a training that is offered almost free of charge.

Can you advise me something else? In addition to being an administrator, I am an application architect and maybe I could do a custom development, maybe using fmpeg or similar.

What do you recommend?

Comment: Assuming that you have a watermark image, you can try this solution to make the watermark move every X seconds : https://write.corbpie.com/creating-a-shifting-watermark-overlay-with-ffmpeg/

Comment: @Rems He would need a text, something that he could pass for example as a parameter in the request, validate it and include it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vf "drawtext=text='Text':x=w-mod(max(t\,0)*(w+tw)/10\,(w+tw)):y=h-text_h:fontsize=24:fontcolor=black:box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5:boxborderw=5" -c:a copy -y output.mp4
```

This will create a text that will scroll horizontally, for the duration of the video

`"drawtext=text='Text'` Change the "Text" here to match what you want

`x=w-mod(max(t\,0)*(w+tw)/10\,(w+tw))` makes the text run across the screen in 10 seconds.

`y=h-text_h` positions the text at the bottom of the video

`black:box=1:boxcolor=white@0.5: boxborderw=5`  creates a frame around the text to make it more visible, but you can remove it

Note that you can use a font file of your choice by adding the "fontfile" option in the filter

Comment: It looks good, but it would generate a file for each resource and for each student. Is there a way for ffmpeg to act as a server and be able to view it, for example in an hmlt component?

Comment: Not sure what you want to do, but ffmpeg doesn't necessarily have to output a file. It can output a stream, if you put this `-` instead of the output file in the command , then you can play this stream in your html component